# (jscolor) How to keep button/input created from DOM empty (color only)

Tags: javascript, html, css, jscolor

I have just discovered the jscolor color picker library and am trying to use it to create unordered lists which can be edited and with each list element having a color picker button associated with it. Doing this requires creating a new button with Javascript via the DOM as opposed to an html file. This is done through a paragraph of code as follows:

```
var newPlayerColor = document.getElementById('colorPicker').value;
    var input = document.createElement('INPUT');
    var newColorButton = new jscolor(input);
    alert(newColorButton.valueElement);
    input.style.backgroundColor = newPlayerColor;
    input.style.height = '20px';
    input.style.width = '20px';
    input.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    newDiv.appendChild(input);
```

The above code works fine but it does leave the button with the color hex value displayed inside as text (naming of variables is not yet semamtic so kindly overlook) I want to remove this text leaving only the color (which can still be clicked and used as a color selector). I cannot find any rigorous documentation for the jscolor library but the home website (http://jscolor.com/examples/) does contain an abundance of examples.

One of these examples has the exact functionality I am looking for

```
<button
    class="jscolor {valueElement:null,value:'66ccff'}"
    style="width:50px; height:20px;"></button>
```

The problem is that this is done from the html page and I am unclear how set the valueElement to null (which seems to be doing the trick). Merely inserting     `newColorButton.valueElement = null;` doesn't work nor does something like   `newColorButton.classList.add(' {valueElement:null,value:'66ccff'}'`).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used **jscolor**, but you can clear the text of your button by `input.value = "";`. Just add this line in the *'paragraph of code'* before appending it to the DOM.

Comment: Setting input.value = ""; will indeed work BUT as soon as one tries to select a different color the jscolor library will then dynamically place new text back in which corresponds to the newly selected color. Unfortunately I think this is going to have to be solved with the jscolor library itself...

Comment: In that case using the class they provided with `valueElement` is how they think it is supposed to work and you should use it. Another way to go about it is to add an event listener to every button and when it changes the event handler will clear the text.